# Dash/Plotly: How can I plot two columns on the y-axis with the same x axis?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, yaxis

I am trying to plot two columns from my dataset (the columns are 'cases' and 'vaccinations') on the same line graph. The x-axis only has one column (that is, 'country') that I want them to share. Is it possible to do this in Dash/Plotly? I can't find any solutions using Dash. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
                 html.Div(
                    children=dcc.Graph(
                        id="cases-chart",
                        config={"displayModeBar": False},
                        figure={
                            "data": [
                                {
                                    "x": data["country"],
                                    "y": data["cases"],
                                    "type": "lines",
                                },
                            ],
                            "layout": {
                                "title": {
                                    "text": "Cases by Country",
                                    "x": 0.05,
                                    "xanchor": "left",
                                },
                                "xaxis": {"fixedrange": True},
                                "yaxis": {"fixedrange": True},
                                "colorway": ["#17B897"],
                            },
                        },
                    ),
                    className="card",
                ),
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another element to the "data" list with the wanted data.

You can find more info in [the documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/graph)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
"data": [
                                {
                                    "x": data["country"],
                                    "y": data["vaccinations"],
                                    "type": "lines",
                                },
                                {
                                    "x": data["country"],
                                    "y": data["cases"],
                                    "type": "lines",
                                }
                            ],
```